# Excel custom sorting with custom cmp

Tags: python, excel, vba

Im totaly new in excel nor in VBA.

I need to write a VBA macro that will sort dogs by total gained points and if the points are same then check each atribute (from left to right) and sort by these.

I wrote some (i think) working sort in python:

```
import random
from functools import cmp_to_key
class Structure:
    def __init__(self,total,agility,speed,endurance,follow,enthusiasm):
        self.total = total
        self.agility = agility
        self.speed = speed
        self.endurance = endurance
        self.follow = follow
        self.enthusiasm = enthusiasm

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Structure(Total=' + str(self.total) + ' ,agility=' + str(self.agility) +' ,speed=' + str(self.speed) + ' ,endurance=' + str(self.endurance)+\
               ' ,follow=' + str(self.follow)+' ,enthusiasm=' + str(self.enthusiasm)+')'


def compare(item1, item2):
    if item1.total < item2.total:
        return -1
    elif item1.total > item2.total:
        return 1
    else:
        #Agility compare
        if(item1.agility>item2.agility):
            return 1
        elif(item1.agility<item2.agility):
            return -1

        #Speed compare
        if(item1.speed>item2.speed):
            return 1
        elif(item1.speed<item2.speed):
            return -1

        #Endurance compare
        if(item1.endurance>item2.endurance):
            return 1
        elif(item1.endurance<item2.endurance):
            return -1
        #Follow compare
        if(item1.follow>item2.follow):
            return 1
        elif(item1.follow<item2.follow):
            return -1
        #Enthusiasm compare
        if(item1.enthusiasm>item2.enthusiasm):
            return 1
        elif(item1.enthusiasm<item2.enthusiasm):
            return -1

        return 0


def fill():
    #total = random.randint(163,170)
    total = 170
    agility = 0
    speed = 0
    endu = 0
    fol = 0
    enth = 0
    while(total!=agility+speed+endu+fol+enth):
        agility = random.randint(20,40)
        speed = random.randint(20,40)
        endu = random.randint(20,40)
        fol = random.randint(20,40)
        enth = random.randint(20,40)
    return [total,agility,speed,endu,fol,enth]


if __name__ == "__main__" :
    list = []
    for i in range(10):
        k = fill()
        list.append(Structure(k[0],k[1],k[2],k[3],k[4],k[5]))
    for i in list:
        print(i)
    print("*********************** after sort *******************")
    zoznam = sorted(list, key=cmp_to_key(compare),reverse=True)
    for i in zoznam:
        print(i)
```

but i have no idea how to write it in excel.

My idea is that i select total numbers and it will sort whole row. The "data structure" in excel looks like this:
[image]

For example as you can see (on top) both of them have total of 170, agility same so pass and speed is higher  so this is why he is on top.

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

Thanks a lot gimix :) Because i need more than three keys and i want only to sort selected ones i "changed" a little bit a macro to:

```
Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("I1"), _
                     Order1:=xlDescending, _
                     Key2:=Range("J1"), _
                     Order2:=xlDescending, _
                     Key3:=Range("K1"), _
                     Order3:=xlDescending, _
                     Header:=xlNo

Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("L1"), _
                     Order1:=xlDescending, _
                     Key2:=Range("G1"), _
                     Order2:=xlDescending, _
                     Key3:=Range("H1"), _
                     Order3:=xlDescending, _
                     Header:=xlNo
```

The thing is, it SEEMS like it is working but i dont know if it SHOULD be "sorted two times" like these, and if there wouldnt be some kind of "leaks" (unwanted behavior)

edit2:

Shouldnt it be rather like this ?

```
Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("K1"), _
                     Order1:=xlDescending, _
                     Header:=xlNo
Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("J1"), _
                     Order1:=xlDescending, _
                     Header:=xlNo
Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("I1"), _
                     Order1:=xlDescending, _
                     Header:=xlNo
Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("H1"), _
                     Order1:=xlDescending, _
                     Header:=xlNo
Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("G1"), _
                     Order1:=xlDescending, _
                     Header:=xlNo

Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("L1"), _
                     Order1:=xlDescending, _
                     Header:=xlNo
```

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro.. of yourself manually sorting them by Total,Agility,Speed.. etc. and then examining the code?

Comment: Can you not just do a multi-column sort? No need for VBA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VBA you have the sort method of the range object:

```vb
Range("A6:L11").Sort Key1:=Range("L1"), _
                     Order1:=xlDescending, _
                     Key2:=Range("G1"), _
                     Order2:=xlDescending, _
                     Key3:=Range("H1"), _
                     Order3:=xlDescending, _
                     Header:=xlNo
```

`Key1` etc identify which column to use; `Order1` etc tell if you want to sort from lowest to highest or the other way round (default is `xlAscending` so you need to specify this); finally `Header` tells if your data has a header row (in your case we use `xlNo` since you have non-data rows between the headers (row1) and the data (row6 and following).

Btw your Python code could be simpler: just create a tuple of `total`, `agility` and `speed` and use it as the `key`: no need for defining a function nor for calling `cmp_to_key()`

Comment: Thanks. It "looks like" its working like i want but, i need more than 3 keys and i dont know if my code (I edited post) is ok

Comment: excel sort is stable, so if you sort on a column with duplicate values the related rows are guaranteed to stay in the same order they were. This means that if you issue more than one sort command (by hand or via code) you need to do them in reversed order: first the least important, and last the most important. But i believe excel can sort up to 64 columns in one pass, so you should not need multiple runs at all

Comment: Sure, maybe we didnt understood each other. Excel sort can do up to 3 keys. Of course I "bypassed" it by doing 6 sorts instead of having 6 keys in one sort. I edited my post, and just wanted to ask you, if that solution dont have holes in it (it looks like it is working). Thanks

Comment: Ok, that's funny. When you select the sort command in a worksheet you can sort many more levels, I assumed the same was true for VBA. You can bypass that limitation of course, and your solution works well; but still I feel MS could have done a better job here